# Возможен ли вызов callback одной функции из другой? JS

Tags: javascript

У меня есть блок с сообщением, который вызывается js функцией  ***showMessage()*** 
Скажем вот это вот блок:

```
<div>
    <label>Вопрос</label>
    <input value="Да" onclick="messageYes();" type="submit">
    <input value="Нет" onclick="messageNo();" type="submit">
    <input value="Отмена" onclick="messageCansel();" type="submit">
</div>
```

JS:

```
function hideMessage(){

}
function messageYes(){

}
function messageNo(){

}
function messageCansel(){

}
function showMessage(error, text, callback){
    При вызове одной из вышеперечисленных функций, нужно вызвать callback. Либо реализовать это так, чтобы callback вызывался при клике на кнопки.
}
```

Comment: `callback` передается в функцию `showMessage` передавай его в остальные функции и все. Непонятно как связаны указанные три функции с функцией `showMessage`

Comment: В том то и дело, что они никак не связаны. Эти три функции вызываются при клике на кнопки в появившемся сообщении. Мне нужно перехватить событие этого клика в showMessage  и вызвать каллбек.

Comment: Все равно непонятно, что ты хочешь сделать. Попробуй описать более подробно, стоит добавить пример кода, как бы ты хотел чтобы это выглядело. Отредактировать вопрос, чтобы добавить всю необходимую информацию можно с помощью кнопки [edit]

Comment: Прошу прощение за неточности и неполное раскрытие вопроса. Постарался исправить.

Comment: @Tima Вызывайте showMessage в конце каждой функции

Comment: @Save14, `showMessage` судя из объяснения, показывает блок, в котором кнопки с обработчиками, если в этих обработчиках опять вызывать `showMessage` будет не совсем ожидаемое поведение

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Использован неверный подход.

В текущем виде нет никакой связи между указанными тремя функциями, и функцией `showMessage`. Из-за этого единственное решение - внутри функции `showMessage` записывать переданный callback в глобальную переменную, которую и использовать потом в указанных функциях:

```
var globalCallback;
function messageCancel(){
    ...
    globalCallback(...);
    ...
}
function showMessage(error, text, callback){
    ...
    globalCallback = callback;
    ...
}
```

---

Вместо этого можно просто присваивать обработчики из скрипта, и передавать в них нужный callback, например:

```js
function hideMessage(el) {
  console.log('hide');
  $(el).closest('.msg').remove();
}

function messageYes(callback) {
  console.log('messageYes');
  callback(this);
}

function messageNo(callback) {
  console.log('messageNo');
  callback(this);
}

function messageCancel(callback) {
  console.log('messageCancel');
  callback(this);
}

function showMessage(error, text, callback) {
  $('.template').clone().toggleClass('template').appendTo('body') // создаем элемент для сообщения
    // добавляем обработчики для кнопок
    .find('.yes').click(function() {
      messageYes.call(this, callback);
    }).end()
    .find('.no').click(function() {
      messageNo.call(this, callback);
    }).end()
    .find('.cancel').click(function() {
      messageCancel.call(this, callback);
    });
};

function show() {
  showMessage('', '', hideMessage);
}
```

```css
.template {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="msg template">
  <label>Вопрос</label>
  <input value="Да" class="yes" type="submit">
  <input value="Нет" class="no" type="submit">
  <input value="Отмена" class="cancel" type="submit">
</div>

<input type="button" value="show message" onclick="show()" />
```